# ios xcode where are autolayout constraints stored?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

In android when you make an app then you can watch the layout xml files at project folders, but in iOS i cant find any files about autolayout constraints at any folder of the project.

When you use autolayout in xcode, the constraints data are saved at any folder of the project? Is there any way to find them at the project files?

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean inside each xib? You can click right on the xib file, and choose Open as Source Code and find them.

Comment: You can open your storyboard with TextEdit or etc. You will see everything there.

Comment: If you added them in interface builder they are in the interface builder file. Down the left hand side you will see all the constraints (blue icons). I suggest not editing the XML directly unless you want a nib that you can't open. Much better to edit the properties of them in interface builder. That's what it is there for.

Comment: Thank u. All are stored at storyboard file. Anyway I prefer the xml layouts of android :S